# How device driver write/read works

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Custom read and write operations are defined as

```
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *,char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *,const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

What happens when a read or write is made to a device?

I couldnt find simple explanation of this in LDD book.

For example what happens when I have a device and I made a write like

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/newdevice
```

And I am writing a simple character device. Also

```
cat  /dev/newdevice
```

I know it depends on my custom read/write and what I need is simple read from memory and write to memory

Comment: What exactly do you not understand from the explanation in LDD?

Comment: `(struct file *,char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);` ? What happens when a string is written to a file?

Comment: The `write` function is called, with the parameter values as described in LDD.

Answer (score 2):

@user567879, Since device node is treated as a special character or block or a network file, each file has an **file structure "filp"** which in turn holds the pointer to the **file operations table** where each system call is mapped to appropriate functions in device driver.

```
for ex: .open = my_open
        .write = my_write 
        .read = my_read etc.
```

What happens when you issue echo "Hello" > /dev/newdevice is

```
1) Device node i.e. "/dev/newdevice" is opened using open system call which in turn 
   calls your mapped open function i.e. "**my_open**"

2) If open is successful, write system call issued with appropriate file descriptor 
   (fd), which in turn calls "**my_write**" function present in device driver and thus 
   according to the functionality it writes/transmits user data to the actual 
   hardware. 

3) Same rule applies for "cat  /dev/newdevice" i.e. open the device node --> read 
   system call --> mapped read function in your device driver i.e. "**my_read**" --> 
   reads the data from actual hardware and sends the data read from the hardware to
   user space (application which issued read system call)
```

I hope I have answered your question :-)

Comment: What are the parameters to these functions?

Comment: Which functions are your referring to? is it system call parameters or mapped functions in your device drivers?

Comment: `(struct file *,char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);` ? What happens when a string is written to a file?

Comment: First it will check whether opened file is readonly or read-write, if readwrite then string passed by user space application is then queued up and then string is been written into the specified file with the help of write system call which in-turn calls device driver mapped write function. Write to a file will not happen immediately, because it involves hardware (I/O operation) and also write/read to/from memory devices are very slow and in a sequence. Block device driver architecture will explain you better about read/write to a file.